# How to remove "gap" className by TailwindCSS in NextJS component?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I work right now on buttons components in NextJS with Tailwindcss and need some variants. Everything is fine, but when I remove **children** (Button text) I have some strange thing which I don't understand.
If button have text + icon = work good. Single icon = there is some space on the left. How to remove it?

I'll tried to remove gap and add padding to text, but still the empty space is not removed

[My Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEAOZ.jpg)

My code:
**Index**

```
import { ElevatedButton } from "../components";
import { MdDataSaverOff } from "react-icons/md";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <>
       <ElevatedButton
        iconRight={<MdDataSaverOff size={18} />}
        type={"tonal"}
      ></ElevatedButton>
    </>
 );
}
```

**Component**

```
import { Icon } from "../../../elements/Icon";

function ElevatedButton(props) {
  return (
    <>
      <button className={`btn ${props.type}`} onClick={props.onClick}>
        <Icon iconLeft={props.iconLeft} />
        <p>{props.children}</p>
        <Icon iconRight={props.iconRight} />
      </button>
    </>
  );
}

export { ElevatedButton };
```

**Element**

```
function Icon(props) {
  return (
    <>
      {props.iconLeft}
      {props.iconRight}
    </>
  );
}

export { Icon };
```

**Tailwind**

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer components {
  /*Common Buttons*/
  .btn {
    @apply mt-[4px] flex h-[40px] items-center gap-[8px] rounded-full py-[10px] px-[24px];
  }

  .elevated {
    @apply bg-blue-500;
  }

  .tonal {
    @apply bg-blue-100;
  }
}
```

[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsvSY.jpg)

[Screenshot 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncV1N.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I got it, we're removing text from the div element's, but we're not removing the div itself. Therefore, when applying the gap style, space is added between the elements. And the following will be correct: completely remove the div wrapper

```
import { Icon } from "../../../elements/Icon";

function ElevatedButton(props) {
  return (
    <>
      <button className={`btn ${props.type}`} onClick={props.onClick}>
        <Icon iconLeft={props.iconLeft} />
        {props.children}
        <Icon iconRight={props.iconRight} />
      </button>
    </>
  );
}

export { ElevatedButton };
```